# How to change a value of IObservable<double>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am new at RX, right now I am try to do the easy thing - just to set a new value to IObservable (in my case T is double). How to do it?

```
   public IObservable<double> TEST
    {
        get { return _test.NeededValue; }
        set { _test.NeededValue = value; } // I have add this, in order to change needed value
    }
    ...
    myObj.TEST = 0.1; // error 'Cannot convert double to System.IObservable<double>
```

Comment: can you describe not working? i.e. error messages if any, incorrect values etc.?

Comment: I haven't done that much in C# but, `IObservable` seems to be an interface, I don't think you can instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pretty much the simplest way to get an observable to produce a value:

```
Subject<double> subject = new Subject<double>();
IObservable<double> observable = subject.AsObservable();
observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
subject.OnNext(42);
```

This will output `42` to the console.

I've included the line `IObservable<double> observable = subject.AsObservable();` to show what you should do, but as a `Subject<T>` is also an `IObservable<T>` you can actually just do this:

```
Subject<double> subject = new Subject<double>();
subject.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
subject.OnNext(42);
```

Now, this isn't overly interesting.

This might match your needs some more:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Bars.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    foo.OnBar(42);
}

public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler<double> Bar;

    public void OnBar(double value)
    {
        this.Bar?.Invoke(this, value);
    }

    public IObservable<double> Bars
    {
        get
        {
            return
                Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<double>, double>(
                        h => this.Bar += h,
                        h => this.Bar -=h)
                    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
        }
    }   
}
```

This code also prints `42` to the console.